# PDO fails to prepare a statement with over 13 placeholders

Tags: php, pdo

this is the code I'm using:

```
self::$DB->prepare($query, $types);
```

when the $query and types are:

```
//$query
UPDATE Permisos
    SET                 
        empleado_id = ?,
        agregar_mensaje = ?,
        borrar_mensaje = ?,
        agregar_noticia = ?,
        borrar_noticia = ?,
        agregar_documento = ?,
        borrar_documento = ?,
        agregar_usuario = ?,
        borrar_usuario = ?,
        agregar_empresa = ?,
        borrar_empresa = ?,
        agregar_tarea = ?
    WHERE
        id = ?
//$types
Array(
    [0] => integer
    [1] => boolean
    [2] => boolean
    [3] => boolean
    [4] => boolean
    [5] => boolean
    [6] => boolean
    [7] => boolean
    [8] => boolean
    [9] => boolean
    [10] => boolean
    [11] => boolean
    [12] => integer
)
```

Everything works great, but when they are:

```
//$query
UPDATE Permisos SET                         
         empleado_id = ?,
         agregar_mensaje = ?,
         borrar_mensaje = ?,
         agregar_noticia = ?,
         borrar_noticia = ?,
         agregar_documento = ?,
         borrar_documento = ?,
         agregar_usuario = ?,
         borrar_usuario = ?,
         agregar_empresa = ?,
         borrar_empresa = ?,
         agregar_tarea = ?,
         borrar_tarea = ?
    WHERE
id = ?
//$types
Array(
        [0] => integer
        [1] => boolean
        [2] => boolean
        [3] => boolean
        [4] => boolean
        [5] => boolean
        [6] => boolean
        [7] => boolean
        [8] => boolean
        [9] => boolean
        [10] => boolean
        [11] => boolean
        [12] => boolean
        [13] => integer
    )
```

It fails with the following message:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  PDO::prepare() [<a href='pdo.prepare'>pdo.prepare</a>]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a string specifying an existing class in <b>C:\wamp\www\intratin\JP\includes\empleado\mapper\Permiso.php</b> on line <b>137</b><br />
```

Doesn't matter which field I add or remove, it fails every time with more than 13 placeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `self::$DB->prepare` method is actually calling [`PDO::prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), make sure that you don't pass that `$types` argument as a second parameter to `PDO::prepare`

Judging from the documentation, the second parameter that `PDO::prepare` expects is an array of options -- not an array describing the type of data for each placeholder.

And you try to execute this portion of code :

```
var_dump(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS);
```

You'll get this output :

```
int 13
```

Which kind of explains the error :

- You are trying to pass to `PDO::prepare` and array as second parameter
- `PDO::prepare` expects that array to contain a list of options
- You have an element with key `13` in your array
- `13` is `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS`
- `PDO::preapre` expects something specific for the `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS` option

  - like something corresponding to `array(classname, array(ctor_args));`, judging from your error message
- You're passing `integer` instead of that
- So you get an error.

Not sure how you can specify the types of each bound parameters with the class you are using -- but it seems it's not as a second parameter to `prepare` ;-)

And, if your `self::$DB` is indeed an instance of PDO, I don't find a method that would allow you to specify the types of all parameters at once -- it seems you have to specify the type for each parameter, each time you call either [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [`bindValue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I migrated from MDB2 and thought, cool, same syntax because it worked, until now :$

Is there any way to pass the types to PDO::prepare so it escapes them properly, or is that unnecesary?

Comment: I don't think you can pass all the types in only one call... I'd say you have to pass them one by one, when you're calling `bindParam` or `bindValue` : you're already passing the values using one of those two -- and they both can take the type as an optionnal parameter ;;; if you know the type of your data, passing it cannot hurt ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, if you don't care too much about the types (AFAIK they'll all be PDO::PARAM_STR; you can't specify them when you're not using bindValue/bindParam):

```
$params = array('your', 'params', 'here', '...'); // just the params, not the type
$stmnt = self::$DB->prepare($query);
$stmnt->execute($params);
```

See PDOStatement's [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method.

Comment: Thanks, FYI there is a bug with PDO statements where it quotes integers in queries: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639
Even if their PHP types are integers, so until that's fixed you're bound to bind them :S